# When Is it possible to define a ''Integral surface''?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

An integral curve $c(t)$ of a vector field $V$ on a manifold $M$ is defined as the solution of $\frac{dc(t)}{t}=V(c(t))$, here we require that $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it possible to define an integral surface $s$ of two vector fields $V_1,V_2$,  i.e.  a map $\mathbb{R}^2 \supset \Delta \longrightarrow M$,  $t=(t_1,t_2)\mapsto s(t_1,t_2)$, such that $\frac{\partial s}{\partial t_1}=V_1(s)$ and $\frac{\partial s}{\partial t_2}=V_2(s)$ ?

I tried to define $s(t_1,t_2)$ by firstly fixing $t_2$,  we go from the initial point $p=s(0,0)$ through the integral curve of $V_1$ for time $t_1$, the $s(t_1,0)$ is defined as the point where we are now, then fix $t_1$ and go through the integral curve of $V_2$ for time $t_2$ and define $s(t_1,t_2)$ as the point where we are now.

But I know this is wrong since if we instead go through integral curve of $V_2$ first, we will get another point if the Lie bracket $[V_1,V_2]\neq 0$.

So when is this system of PDE ($\frac{\partial s}{\partial t_1}=V_1(s)$ ,$\frac{\partial s}{\partial t_2}=V_2(s)$ ) solvable, is it solvable only if $[V_1,V_2]=0$ ? I don't much knowledge in PDE theory so I apologize if this question is too naive.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite. You need the Lie bracket to be in the span of the two vector fields. The relevant theorem is the Frobenius Theorem. You can try it for yourself. You can see that there is no surface everywhere (even locally) tangent to the vector fields $V_1=(1,0,0)$ and $V_2=(0,1,x)$ on $\Bbb R^3$. (Hint: Near the origin it would have to be the graph of a smooth function, $z=\phi(x,y)$.)